# Finding elements that appear in n number of lists in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I am working on a personal code to do some things for a research analysis. 
I have a list of list with 14 lists and I want to find elements that are shared between at least 10 of those lists. Here is what I have so far which finds shared elements in all of the lists. I also wrote one that outputs if an element appears greater than 10 times, which isn't working for my purposes because some of the lists in the list of list have multiples of the same value. Below is my example code.

```
  def find_duplicates(master_list):
    result = set(master_list[0])
    for organism in master_list[1:]:
        result.intersection_update(organism)
    x = list(result)
    with open("duplicates.txt", "wt") as t:
        for a in x:
            t.write(a + "\n")
```

## version two

```
def find_duplicates(master):
    new = []
    for organism in master:
        for feature in organism:
            if sum(organism.count(feature) for organism in master) == 10:
                if y not in new:
                   new.append(y)
   with open("duplicates_list.txt", "wt") as t:
     for a in new:
        t.write(a + "\n")
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could modify this to find elements that are in at least 10 of the lists in my list of lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order does not matter you can use a Counter dict to do the counting, call set on each sublist to get unique values:

```
from collections import Counter
def find_duplicates(master):
    cn = Counter(feature for organism in master for feature in set(organism))
    with open("duplicates_list.txt", "wt") as t:
      for k,v in cn.items():
         if v >= 10:
             t.write("{}\n".format(k))
```

For `v` i.e the count to be at least 10 there will be at least 10 sublists that have the particular feature as `set(organism)` ensures even if a feature appears more then once we only see it once as our set cannot have duplicates.